# Modest changes in LaTeX dialect possible?

Tags: preamble, markup

I would like to create my own LaTeX-derivative markup language.  (I asked similar questions before, but this is more limited.)  Advice would be useful.

#### First Question:

I believe there are three main categories of macros between the begin-document and end-document (which I will call the "main document"):

1. markup (e.g., `\textit`, `\begin{quote}`)
2. characters (e.g., `\kappa`, `\Bbb{A}`)
3. programming (e.g., `\newcommand`, `\let`, `\newtheorem`).

Is this classification reasonable, or am I omitting a logical class of macros?

I believe everything that can be typeset in LaTeX can still be typeset if I removed #3 from the main document and banned it into the preamble.  This means that once my preamble is read, the set of allowed macro names will be fixed, and I just have true markup in my document.  Another program could then, in principle, interpret markup (and interpret it differently) without having to be itself TeX.

#### Second Question:

Is there a long-cut to `{ }` environments?  This is when used by itself, not when used to delineate arguments of macros.  I mean `hello {\it there}` as opposed to `hello \textit{there}`.  I am wondering if I can "ban" the plain environment use of the parens in my document, and rely on styling instead.  In rare cases where needed, I would then say `\begin{env} ... \end{env}`.  But I have not run into such a situation.

#### Third question:

Is it possible to change catcodes in the main document, but as soon as LaTeX expands (enters = runs) a macro, the standard catcode definitions hold again?  (I.e., so that I can still run all macros that were defined in packages without me having to make changes).

If this is the case, then I could define my own LaTeX dialect.  My documents would have the power of standard LaTeX in the preamble, and then

```
\usepackage[version=2]{newdocument}
\begin{newdocument}
   modified catcodes, outside markup
\end{newdocument}
```

where the newdocument would be my own version.  as for me, I would want

- `|` becomes my cell separator in tabulars
- `&` become the entity operator, just as in html, i.e., `&amp;kappa;` and `&hashmark;`
- `\\` be replaced with something like `\nl`
- `$` be freed up (i.e., no longer a catcode).  my users would have to use `\m{...}` for math expressions.
- `%` be freed up (i.e., no longer be a special catcode).  15% is now what it should be.

Less important:

- `#` become the remark operator.  without programming, no longer needed otherwise
- `\#` be banned in exchange for `&hashmark;`

Now, processing the input text is easy with Lua or Perl or..., but I would like the documents to remain portable, so this would have to be a standard LaTeX package written in TeX.  (If this is easy, I will want to hire someone to implement this.  If this is hard, then it's a no go.)

/iaw

Comment: Modest changes? ;-) You can ban `\it`, just remove its definition; but you can't really ban users to type `{\itshape world}` if they want. You can't also avoid them using `\newcommand` mid document: undefining it would break umpteen packages.

Comment: Everything you describe is pretty straightforward.  For an example of what can be done, the `xmltex` package lets you insert xml into a TeX file and typeset the `<div>...</div>` and other things correctly.

Comment: (old question but) Regarding question 2, note that some macro uses explicit `{}` to start/end group in its argument, so be careful. You'd need to check where the token *comes from* before executing it, so best way is to patch TeX the engine, I guess.

Comment: (some time later) I guess it's possible to do `\tracingcommands=1 \tracinggroups=1`, then replace every `{}` that appears in your code with corresponding tokens with special char code, then grep the log for `{begin-group character x}` followed by `{entering simple group...}` -- note that package code might enter simple group and you usually don't want to prohibit them; but then most nice packages will use semi-simple group instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 3 is yes. You can see this e.g. for @: its catcode in a document is other but \section has no problem to call the internal \@startsection.

You can also easily test it:

```
\documentclass{article}

%normal catcodes:
\newcommand\test{$a_b$}

\begin{document}

\catcode`\$=11
\catcode`_=11
%changed catcodes:
$a_b$

\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you ulrike.  \textit{$a_b$} also works appropriately.